# Why Comparable is not declared as @FunctionalInterface in jdk 1.8 though it is one of the FunctionalInterface?

Tags: java, interface, java-8, functional-interface

Comparable and Comparator are Functional Interface and Comparator is declared as @FunctionalInterface also but why Comparable is not declared as @FunctionalInterface in jdk 1.8 though it is one of them?

example:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

`Comparable` is *technically* a functional interface, but it makes no sense to actually implement it with a lambda.  `Comparable` objects really have to have *other state* that you're trying to compare, and you're supposed to compare two objects of the *same type.*  Neither of those make sense for a lambda.

Comment: Yeah it makes sense. Thank you for your clearification.